# TSQL 2008 How to make columns for views unique

Tags: t-sql, view

I have a query I am trying to save as a view but SSMS returns an error stating there are multiple columns with the same name.

I have tried to rename the affected columns as an alias but without success.

Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'codemanQuestionID' in view or function 'vwBlocks' is specified more than once.

```
create view vwBlocks as


SELECT        

LUConstructionType.codemanOptionID AS LUConstruction_codemanOptionID

, LUFascias.codemanOptionID AS LUFascias_codemanOptionID
, Block.windowsID
, LUWindows.windows
, LUWindows.codemanQuestionID AS codemanQuestion_ID

, Block.externalDoorID
, LUExternalDoor.externalDoor
, LUExternalDoor.codemanOptionID as LUExternal_codemanOptionID

FROM            Block LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUOwnership ON Block.ownershipID = LUOwnership.ownershipID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LULocalAuthority ON Block.localAuthorityID = LULocalAuthority.authorityTypeID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUConstructionType ON Block.constructionTypeID = LUConstructionType.constructionTypeID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUTV ON Block.TVID = LUTV.TVID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUSatellite ON Block.satelliteID = LUSatellite.satelliteID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUPlayArea ON Block.playArea = LUPlayArea.playAreaID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LURoofCovering ON Block.roofCoveringID = LURoofCovering.roofCoveringID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUFascias ON Block.fasciasID = LUFascias.fasciasID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUWindows ON Block.windowsID = LUWindows.windowsID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUExternalDoor ON Block.externalDoorID = LUExternalDoor.externalDoorID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUcontractorInfo ON Block.contractorInfoID = LUcontractorInfo.contractorID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUagentInfo ON Block.agentInfoID = LUagentInfo.agentID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LULandlord ON Block.LandlordID = LULandlord.landlordID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUblockStatus ON Block.blockStatusID = LUblockStatus.blockStatusID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUPropertyGroup ON Block.propertyGroup = LUPropertyGroup.propertyGroupID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUCommunalBoilerType ON Block.communalBoilerType = LUCommunalBoilerType.communalBoilerID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUExternalAreaManagedBy ON Block.externalAreaManagedBy = LUExternalAreaManagedBy.managedByID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUgasBoilerMakeModel ON Block.CommBoilerMakeModelID = LUgasBoilerMakeModel.makeModelId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         LUMaintenanceResp ON Block.maintenanceRepID = LUMaintenanceResp.maintenanceRepID
```

Can anybody recommend a solution please?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing codemanQuestionID twice. Here's some advice that has helped me a ton avoid and/or troubleshoot issues like this.

There are at least four ways to alias a column:

1. (expression) AS ((alias))
2. ((alias)) = (expression)
3. WITH ((cte name)) ((alias1), (alias2),...
4. FROM ((subquery)) AS ((alias1>),(alias2,...

AS  is the worst IMO. Its sloppy and confusing, especially when you don't include AS. The aliasing style I usually go with is:

```
SELECT
   col1   = <expression>,
   col2   = <expression>,
   colABC = <expression>
FROM  schema.table1 AS t1
JOIN  schema.table2 AS t2;
```

This has made debugging  waaay easier.